# Flutter syncfusion date range picker - type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

**What was intended?**

I'm using syncfusion in flutter, and specifically working with the date range picker.
I'm trying to verify that the start date and end date are valid, meaning the range does not contain any rented out days - which in my code is marked as special days.

**What is the problem?**

Then I have the following block of code within my `onSelectionChanged` method

```
bool selectionIsValid = true;

DateTime startDate = args.value.startDate;
DateTime endDate = args.value.endDate;

for (DateTime rentedOutDay in rentOutTimes) {
  if (rentedOutDay.isAfter(startDate) && rentedOutDay.isBefore(endDate)) {
    selectionIsValid = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

This does not work for some reason as it gives the following error
`type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'`

I have verified that `args.value.startDate` is of type DateTime
the same with `args.value.endDate`, and even assigned them to a variable of DateTime type.

In the run window it complains about the if-statement, and nowhere else.
Specifically the condition part of the if-statement

If the selected range is not valid it basically just does this
`DateRangePickerController().selectedDate = startDate = endDate = DateTime.now();`

So, assigns today's date as the value to save and then continues as usual.

It's not a breaking error - it just doesn't work as intended

**What have I tried?**

I have tried to assign the `args.value.startDate` and `args.value.endDate` to variables that are specifically DateTime objects

I have also tried to do a null check beforehand, which basically doesn't run any code in the `onSelectionChanged` method if any of the values are null - this did nothing in the end.

Comment: can you provide a sample full snippet